# How to implement logout in apollo-client

Tags: stack, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

The authentication example found in the apollo docs is as follows:

https://github.com/apollostack/core-docs/blob/master/source/network.md#afterware

````
```
networkInterface.useAfter([{
  applyAfterware({ response }, next) {
    if (response.status === 401) {
      logout();
    }
    next();
  }
}]);
```
````

But what does the logout function look like?  I'm unclear how to actually dispatch this as an action if it is indeed an action.  The docs are really unclear on this and I haven't been able to find any example code anywhere.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Look at my implementation:

```
const withUserHandlers = withHandlers({
  logout: props => () => {
    const { client, navigation, setUser } = props; // eslint-disable-line
    removeTokenFromUse(client);
    client.resetStore();
    setUser(null);

    const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
       index: 0,
       actions: [ NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' }) ],
    });
    navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
  }
});
```